# Can't import certain tables from SQL Server to QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, sql-server, query, import

[image: This is a list of 193 zip codes and their geometries that do not import in QGIS.]
This is a list of 193 zip codes and their geometries that do not import in QGIS.

[image: This is a list of 999 Census Block Groups and their geometries that do import in QGIS.]
This is a list of 999 Census Block Groups and their geometries that do import in QGIS.

[image: This is the Add MSSQL Layer tbl in QGIS. It shows what the table displays when I try to import them both.]
This is the Add MSSQL Layer tbl in QGIS. It shows what the table displays when I try to import them both.

What would cause one table to be able to import, but not the other?

I am having this problem where I can't import shapefiles from SQL to QGIS. I am using zip codes in Florida as my shapes. I wrote a query in sql to give me certain zip codes and their geometries for certain counties in FL. This was put into a new table in sql consisting of nearly 200 zip codes. When I try to import this into QGIS, it wont import. The MSSQL import table doesnt allow me to select this table. However, if I change the query to include only 20 zip codes, it will allow me to select and import the table. So does QGIS have a limit to the amount of shapes it can import? I have other tables in sql that have more than 1000 shapes and they import, but not this one of 200 zip codes.

Comment: Do you have a unique id column primary key on the table in mssql?

Comment: @MortenFuglsang, I added a unique ID, i.e. assigned an individual integer value to each row. Still having the same problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed that QGIS up to my current version (2.12.2) appears to have a problem loading MSSQL geometries of type "GeometryCollection", when you would expect Polygons or Multipolygons. To check if you have these, use:

```sql
SELECT GEOM.STGeometryType() FROM [yourtable]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this free software, [Spatial Data Manager](http://mapet.altervista.org).
I found that it is the only free software that can [load spatial data](http://mapet.altervista.org/#!sdm-documentation-sdm) directly between the major RDBMS.
You can filter your data during the export operation.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, but why use this when QGIS has the Add MSSQL layer option?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question very quickly and I confused QGIS with PostGIS, thinking that the problem was to load data from MSSQL to PostGIS. Now I understand the problem. Have you checked if the geometries are correct? To do this you can use the software tools that I have indicated ("Check Geometry") or run the following SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <yourtable> WHERE <yourgeometrycol>.STIsValid() = 0